# mysql query not returning all results when using case

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get data from two tables . The first table is of sub category and the second is of sub category image . There is only one sub category which has image and the rest of them does not have a image . I made the following query so that the one which do not have a image can be with a default image

```
select s.name,s.id,s.level,CASE WHEN g.photo_url IS NULL THEN 'no-image.png'  ELSE g.photo_url END AS photo_url  
from sub_category s,gallery g 
where g.main_id=s.id and g.type_id='9' and s.category_id='1' and s.level='1'
```

But it is returning one row ( the one which had image) and rest of the sub categories are not even shown .It was suppose to show 7 sub category one with the image and the rest of them with the default image for all of those who don't have a image in gallery table.

Comment: Your implicit `INNER JOIN` limits your output.  Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `left join`

also use explicit join syntax.

```
select s.name,s.id,s.level,
CASE WHEN g.photo_url IS NULL THEN 'no-image.png'  
ELSE g.photo_url END 
AS photo_url  
from sub_category s
left join gallery g 
on g.main_id=s.id 
on g.type_id='9' 
where s.category_id='2' 
and s.level='1'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply . But its giving mysql error where left join starts

Comment: @user1001176, there was extra comma left behind, try now

Comment: removing the comma now gives sub category of all categories . I wanted all sub categories with category id 1 .

Comment: @user1001176, in that case, you need to use where clause.

Comment: Now using the where clause . its again showing only 1 result :(

Comment: i managed to get the results i wanted :) . Can you please this one above ill mark this as correct `select s.name,s.id,s.level,
CASE WHEN g.photo_url IS NULL THEN 'no-image.png'  
ELSE g.photo_url END 
AS photo_url  
from sub_category s
left join gallery g 
on g.main_id=s.id and
g.type_id='9'
where  s.category_id='2' 
and s.level='1'`